# QIWI ссылка Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, qiwi

Всем добрый день. Как проводите майские праздники? Делаю бота для телеграмм на Python, возник вопрос по поводу ссылки для оплаты на киви кошелёк. API от QIWI здесь не пригодится, можно просто взять чью-то готовую ссылку, заменить сумму и номер телефона и сработает. Правда ли это? Как сделать такую ссылку, с фиксированной суммой, и если пользователь переходит по этой ссылке, то его перебрасывает на официальный сайт QIWI и сразу открывается страница с оплатой с этой же самой фиксированной суммой на определённый номер телефона (я так понял номер телефона тоже указывается ссылка). Как сделать такую ссылку? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: https://r0664n.site/gio/redirect.php?amount=50&comment=827190946 Вот нашел рандомный пример (это не реклама, ничего), где amount это сумма, но номера телефона тут нет, тут видимо указывается сайт. А как указать номер телефона ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А копилка не подойдёт ?
`QIWI Копилка – быстрый и удобный инструмент для сбора средств. Чтобы создать Копилку, необходимо авторизоваться на сайте qiwi.me, указав цели сбора средств. После этого пользователь получит ссылку на свою копилку, которой он может поделиться с друзьями, семьей или коллегами. Для создания копилки необходимо иметь аккаунт в Visa QIWI Кошельке. В случае его отсутствия нужно пройти регистрацию и идентификацию на qiwi.com.`

/киви касса допускает возврат средств, а копилка нет.

Answer (score 2):

Указанная ссылка редиректит на Киви, где в адресе указан айдишник их Qiwi-аккаунта. То есть, номер телефона в URL'e не указывается.

Самое правильное для понимания вопроса – посмотреть в документацию, а не гадать на кофейной гуще о возможностях системы. У Киви-Кассы [есть метод АПИ для выставления счёта](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/bill-payments/#create), которому скармливаются нужные параметры, после он возвращает ссылку для оплаты, и уже на неё нужно перевести Вашего клиента. А перед этим, конечно же, надо зарегистрироваться на сайте и авторизоваться в АПИ из своего кода.